# Qt: How to display a Messagebox when you are within a function?

Tags: c++, qt, button, messagebox

I'm developing using the Qt Nokia SDK.

I'm having trouble displaying the buttons of a MessageBox, when trying to display a messagebox within a function. If i try to display it within the main window, there is no problem showing the buttons.

The mainwindow consist of a QStackWidget which holds different widgets.

Here is the code that works in main window:

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText("Name");
msgBox.setInformativeText("Do you want to save your changes?");
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard |
                          QMessageBox::Cancel);
msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Save);
int ret = msgBox.exec();
```

Here is the function and code that i run after receiving a response from a web request (The messagebox displays, but not the buttons.

```
void MainWindow::RequestReceived()
{
    QMessageBox *msgBox = new QMessageBox(this);
    msgBox->setText("Test");
    msgBox->setWindowModality(Qt::NonModal);
    msgBox->setInformativeText("Do you want to save your changes?");
    msgBox->setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | 
                               QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgBox->setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Save);
    int ret = msgBox->exec();
}
```

Anyone got an idea of what is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I  can't reproduce your problem. There shouldn't be any. Are you sure you aren't interfering with the QMessageBox somewhere else?

Comment: Can't spot your problem, but if that is the exact code, make sure to fix that memory leak.

Comment: @netrom: Have you also added the QStackWidget to the MainWindow?

Comment: @Ikky: I guess you mean QStackedWidget and yes I have, no problems at all.

Comment: another problem: setWindowModality(Qt::NonModal) and then call with exec()

Comment: What version of qt, and what system do you use?

Comment: I'd certainly want to try with multiple other Qt versions.  It sounds like a bug.

Comment: You create 1 message box with a parent widget and the other without. Don't know if that makes any difference in your case.

Comment: hmm, weird... when i lanch the application on a device, the buttons are shown, but not in the emulator...

Answer (score 14):

Try this code.It will help you.

```
QMessageBox Msgbox;
    int sum;
    sum = ui->textEdit->toPlainText().toInt()+ ui->textEdit_2->toPlainText().toInt();
    Msgbox.setText("sum of numbers are...."+sum);
    Msgbox.exec();
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this will help:

```
QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;

reply = QMessageBox::question(this, "Save", "Do you want to save your changes?",
    QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | QMessageBox::Cancel);

if (reply == QMessageBox::Save) {
    qDebug() << "Yes was clicked";
    // code for saving...
}
if (reply == QMessageBox::Discard)
{
    // toDo
}
if(reply == QMessageBox::Cancel)
{
    //toDo
}
```

This code will produce the following:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
QMessageBox *msgBox = new QMessageBox(this);
```

to

```
QMessageBox *msgBox = new QMessageBox(0);
```

Comment: Not setting a parent is never a good idea as it breaks the window stacking (how odd the consequences of that are depends on the platform). It's good practice too always pass a parent.

Comment: Plus, you don't get the QObject hierarchy-based memory management (so it leaks unless you manually delete).